# why can't use Apostrophe( ' ) in token Name,

Tags: tokens, etherscan, nft, polygon, explorers

Polygon explorer/ etherscan explorer

1. **why can't use Apostrophe( ' )  in token Name,** And if I did the explorer shows "&#39"; instead Apostrophe. eg.(cat's = cat+ "&#39"+ s)
2. How can I  address this kind of issue and Is there any solution to change it from explorer side(via contract support).
3. can I change my already deployed contract...

But the return from name() give the correct value only the explorer thows this kind of issue

Comment: wdym by (cat's = cat's) ???

Comment: Sry I think explorer and stackexchanges using same word format.. when I use "&#39" is automatically converted to  Apostrophe( ' )

Comment: The issue you're encountering with token names containing apostrophes (') is related to how HTML entities are used to represent special characters in web pages. In HTML, the apostrophe character is represented as "&#39;" to prevent it from being interpreted as part of the HTML markup.

Comment: Did you try with the character single quotation mark, https://unicodeplus.com/U+2019?